# firefox ipv6 connection failed while tcp layer connected

Tags: http, firefox, firewall, ipv6, windows-firewall

I am trying to connect to an http server via IPv6 link-local address from Windows xp sp3 with firefox 6.
Although connecting by IPv4 address of serve worked well, IPv6 failed with connection failed error.

By Wireshark, the sequence is observed as:

```
         direction    protocol    port         transmission
1. client -> server:  tcp         1061-> 80   [syn]
2. server -> client:  tcp         80->1061    [syn, ack]
3. client -> server:  tcp         1061->80    [ack]
4. client -> server:  http                    [get /]
5. server -> client:  http                    [200 OK]
```

In the 5th transmission, requested html file is included.
But the browser shows connection failed.
It seems tcp layer received the messages and cannot deliver it to http layer or browser.
I disabled firewall, and the result is the same.

Can someone give a clue or hint to pursue.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the whole response in packet 5? That would have to be a tiny response...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's not the whole response in packet 5.

Usually problems like this are caused by broken Path MTU Discovery. If there is a tunnel in the path then the MTU is probably smaller than 1500 bytes, i.e. 1480 bytes. All the packes that are smaller than 1480 bytes get through. When the server sends a 1500 byte packet it will be too big for the tunnel. The tunnel router sends back a Packet-too-big ICMP error, and the server sends the data in 1480-byte chunks. If the ICMP error is never generated or a firewall blocks the ICMP packet then the server never learns that it should send smaller packets, it keeps sending large packets, and they never arrive...

Most of the time such problems are caused by misconfiured firewalls. Sometimes it's broken hardware or software.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sander. I checked the size of packet 5, it was 1475 bytes. And another HTTP redirect message (302 Moved temporarily) of 312 bytes are not received by browser either, in the same transmission sequence.

Comment: For a 302 (Redirected) response, only a new URL is included, it's quite small.

Comment: Ok, so it's really a software issue then, not a network issue. Is it possible for you to send me the full packet dump so I can look at it?

Comment: Hi Sander, thank you for your help, I　sent you the packet dump files to sander@steffann.nl.

Comment: Very strange. It's link-local traffic, so path-MTU problems would indeed be very strange :-)  The packets seem ok, the receiver sends an ACK, so the packet is actually received. I have no idea anymore why the browser isn't seeing the data... Sorry

Comment: You helped to make it clearer that it's probably not a network issue, but a software issue. Thank you. Maybe it is like this one http://www.spywarepoint.com/windows-xp-ipv6-web-browsing-blocked-mcafee-virusscan-9-0-solved-de-installing-mcafee-virusscan-9-0-a-t55978.html, though I need to know which software it is in my windows xp.